# Remove specific parameter from url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

The url is something like this

```
../search/days=4&people=4&stars[]=1&stars[]=2
```

I want to remove the parameter stars[] which is multiple in my case. I tried using below script but it is removing only 1 instance of the parameter but not all.

```
var onlyUrl = window.location.href.replace(/&stars\[\]=\d+/, '');
```

Short & sweet solution is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `..../g` ... will do it - global modifier

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan . That was quick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add /g for a global regex

```
var onlyUrl = window.location.href.replace(/&stars\[\]=\d+/g, '');
```

Comment: Oops! I missed the global modifier /g 

Thanks @alan